# |Discrete Mathematics |The pigeonhole principle + Euclid algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, euclidean-algorithm

We've been given in class of Discrete mathematics a problem which we have to prove using the Pigeonhole principle.

I've been at it for quite a while. Problem is, English is not my first language and writing mathematics in English is even more troublesome so trying to explain what i did so far is a bit problematic.

The sentence which we have to prove:

> let there be a positive integer $n$. $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...,a_{n}$ is an arithmetic
>   progression in which all of it's members are co-primed to $n$
>   $(gcd(n,a_{n})=1)$. Show that the difference of the arithmetic progression 
>   (d) is not co-primed with $n$.

I took $a_{n+1}$ members of the arithmetic progression and put it in n+1 dovecotes. 
each dovecote is the amount of d's used in every member of the series. for example $a_{1}$ had 0 d's in it and $a_{n}$ had n d's in it.

each dovecot of $d$ I distributed into $n-1$ remainders of n. 
using the pigeonhole principles, dividing $n+1$ pigeons (which are the members of the arithmetic series) into n dovecotes, meant there were two pigeons inside the same dovecote. 
$a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n}$ where in the dovecot of remainder 0 (Which means $n$ divides it perfectly).

I subtracted one from the other which gave me:

> $a_{n+1}-a_{1} = a_{1} + (n+1-1)d - a_{1} + (1-1)d = nd$

that is a far as I got.
Sorry for the messy English! Hope I managed to explain what I did so far.
I thought perhaps I should have used the euclidean algorithm at some point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by`$` signs.  `$a_{n+1}$` gives $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: The given arithmetic sequence only has $N$ elements.While you could extend it to $a_{N+1}$, you don't know whether $a_{N+1}$ is coprime to $N$ or not since that is not given in the question, so I don't think doing so is useful.
**Hint:** Consider the remainders you get when dividing $a_i$ by $N$. These are the $N$ pigeons. Their value can be anything from $1$ to $N-1$ (but not $0$) and these are your pigeonholes.

Comment: What is the relation between $n$ and $N$?  Should they be the same?  In the arithmetic progression $8,16$ both elements and the difference $8$ are all relatively prime to $7$.  Why isn't this a counterexample?

Comment: I've corrected the script , hopes it's better now.
Jaap Schrephuis , can you expand more how it correlates with d?